# Task not serializable with spark streaming, cassandra and mllib

Tags: serialization, cassandra, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

i'm developing a streaming classifier using spark streaming, cassandra and MLlib.

When I try to save the result that I get from the model in cassandra, It throws me an exception: Task not serializable.

I have been reading about this error, but I'm not able to find a solution.

This is a sample of my code

```
class StreamingClassificator() extends Serializable
{
    ...

    val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("StreamingClassificator").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CASSANDRA_IP)

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))

    def streaming()
    {
        val results = ... //get data from kafka

        val data = results.map(t => {
            val size = t.size - 1
            var z = new Array[Double](size)
            for (i <- 1 to size - 1) 
            {
              z(i) = t.getDouble(i+1)
            }  
            (t.getDouble(0), LabeledPoint(t.getDouble(1), Vectors.dense(z)))
        })

        data.foreachRDD(rdd => {
            if (rdd.count > 0) 
            {
                val model = RandomForestModel.load(sc, MODEL)    
                val collection = rdd.map // ERROR: Task not serializable
                { 
                    case (id, vector) => { (vector.label, model.predict(vector.features), id) }
                }
                collection.saveToCassandra(...) // Save into cassandra
            }
        })

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()

    }
}

object StreamingClassificatorApp
{
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        val app = new StreamingClassificator()
        app.streaming();
    }
}
```

And this is the error that I get

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)
        at StreamingClassificator$$anonfun$streaming$2.apply(StreamingClassificatorApp.scala:295)
        at StreamingClassificator$$anonfun$streaming$2.apply(StreamingClassificatorApp.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

I think that the problem is that I can not map the rdd in the foreachRDD, buy I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the right answer, but I solve the problem moving the RandomForest model outside of the data.foreachRDD(...) and setting locally the SparkConf and SparkContext

Comment: Had the same issue with SparkStreaming. Moved the SparkConf and the SparkContext from my class constructor to the `public static void main(String[]...` Java method. The spark streaming word count example on [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/exampleshttps://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java) does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Beacause you used sc in `val model = RandomForestModel.load(sc, MODEL)` that makes Spark trying to serialize and transfer that to the executor